# How to access Parents Child in DataColumn Expression

Tags: c#, ado.net, expression, datacolumn

I've a DataSet with 3 DataTables:

> dtPerson
>
> dtSalary
>
> dtFriend

Every person has salaries, and every person has one friend.

I've added a column dcHisFriend into dtSalary and would like to display friend name of a person owning specified salary.

So dtPerson has a column NAME, dtSalary has column VALUE and dtFriend has a column NAME.

I've added column dcHisFriend and set Expression to this:

> dtSalary.Add(dcHisFriend);
>
> dcHisFriend.Expression =
> "Max(Parent.Child(Persons_Friend).NAME)";

But this obviously does not work.

Could you please tell me how to
put into column dcHisFriend name of a friend of a person with a salary into salary table?

Comment: Can you please post the column names of the primary / foreign keys? Meaning, given a salary, how do you get back to Person and how do you get to friend from a salary. Then maybe I'll have a solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, there is no way how to access any other row in "Expression" in DataColumn.

The only way, how to achieve similar behaviour is hook to DataColumnChanged event on DataTables where are source data and then set the computed value to the regular column (=column without expression).

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a way to do this, provided the relationships between your tables are 1 to 1 (though missing rows aren't a huge problem): Create two relations rather than one, i.e.

```
var joinColT1 = table1.Columns["ID"];
var joinColT2 = table2.Columns["FK_IDT1"];
var rel1 = new DataRelation("R1To2", joinColT1, joinColT2, false);
var rel2 = new DataRelation("R2To1", joinColT2, joinColT1, false);
theDataSet.Relations.Add(rel1);
theDataSet.Relations.Add(rel2);
// Add the column you're after
var hisFriend = new DataColumn("HisFriend", typeof(string), "Parent([R2To1]).[HisFriend]");
table1.Columns.Add(hisFriend);
// Add a back-reference to the other table against the friend if you want, too
var hisFriendsSalary = new DataColumn("HisFriendsSalary", typeof(decimal) "Parent([R1To2]).[Salary]");
table2.Columns.Add(hisFriendsSalary);
```

A couple of notes, though: first, when I was first experimenting with this, I got syntax errors without the square brackets around the relation names in the expression. That might just have been to do with the names I'd used for the relations though.

Secondly, I believe the result of Expressions are stored against the rows (they aren't computed "just in time" on access, they're computed when values change, and the results are kept). That means you are storing the data twice by using this approach. Sometimes that's fine, and sometimes it isn't.

Third, you'll note that I'm not using constraints. That's because in my typical use-cases, I'm not expecting every row to have an analogue in the other table (that's why there are two tables in the first place, quite often!). That may (I haven't checked dotnetframework.org) have an impact on performance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarelation
This contains a note which advises not to use bi directional relationships:
"Data corruption can occur if a bi-directional relation is defined between two tables. A bi-directional relation consists of two DataRelation objects that use the same columns, with the parent-child roles switched."